# VSCode No such file or directory when running c++ code

Tags: c++, file, visual-studio-code, include, intellisense

When I try to run [image: my code] I receive this error:

> main.cpp:1:18: fatal error: temp.h: No such file or directory 
>    #include "temp.h"
>   compilation terminated.

Intellisense however, detects that this header is present.
Ctrl + left-clicking on #include "temp.h" in main.cpp successfully brings me to the file and the line of code has no squiggly lines underneath it.

I have two separate folders for .cpp files and header files and have configured the includePath in c_cpp_properties.json as such: [image: c_cpp_properties screenshot]

My workspace folder is temp and the line "${workspaceFolder}/**" should recursively check subfolders for headers.  I added the absolute path to the header files with no success.

Comment: Don't post images for code. Obviously you have an issue with your include paths.

Comment: Is there a `temp.h` is the same directory as the source file `main.cpp`?

Comment: Thank you all for responding. @Someprogrammerdude they are not in the same directory.  I was hoping to keep them in separate folders for organization's sake since VSCode did not auto separate them into separate categories like Visual Studio does.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher  I agree the issue is with my include paths.  I was hoping something concerning the c_cpp_properties could be changed or modified to accommodate having separate source and header folders.  Also sorry for posting code in an image, still new to this.

Answer (score 27):

This question was a result of confusion between the **tasks.json** and the **c_cpp_properties.json** files.  I was treating c_cpp_properties.json as though it was used for compilation.

**c_cpp_properties.json** is used with Intellisense and in no way deals with compilation.

**tasks.json** is used for compilation.  If you're unfamiliar with tasks.json as I was you need to specify the include paths here as well.

In the args section of your tasks.json use "-I" to add an include path, followed by the path you wish to include.

For my problem that command looked like this:

> "-I", "C:\Users\Dill\Desktop\temp\header"

Comment: Note: this does not work with `**` globs to match recursively. You can also do `-IC:\Your\Path` (the `-I` flag without a space immediately followed by the path). And you can use [variable references](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) like `-I${workspaceFolder}`.